# Efficient algorithm to find matching common words or phrases from a corpus

Tags: java, algorithm, text

I am trying to find an efficient way to find common phrases.  I think I can explain better with an example.

Input:  Consider each line as sentence

```
B
B C
A B C B
D E
F D E
```

Output:

```
B
D E
```

Line 2 and 3 are eliminated as B (line 1) is common to them. Line 5 is eliminated as Line 4 is common.

I hope I have explained it!

I can run O(n^2) by doing a match.  Appreciate anything better.

**Update**:  Please consider the order (Eg `D E` should match sentence `F D E`.  `E D` should not.)

Comment: Why don't you add each work to a `HashSet` and when you get a duplicate drop the sentence.  This should be `O(N)`.

Comment: Looks a lot like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8154/how-to-select-minimal-subsets

Comment: @PeterLawrey, how will that handle phrase matches?

Comment: You need an unambiguous definition of 'least common' to write an algorithm! As of now, I don't see what you mean exactly.

Comment: @PS1 you appear to ignore/drop phrase matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I can think to do it would be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> toOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        boolean add = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < toOutput.size(); i++) {
            if (toOutput.get(i).contains(line)) {
                toOutput.remove(i);
            } else if (line.contains(toOutput.get(i))) {
                add = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (add) {
            toOutput.add(line);
        }
    }
    br.close();

    for (String s : toOutput) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

input.txt:

```
B
B C
A B C B
F D E
D E
```

output:

```
B
D E
```

Verify whether or not the current sentence contains any of the Strings that we have currently found unique. I do not believe that there is a more efficient manner of doing it.

Comment: I think it will fail if order of lines is changed. For example if line #5 comes before line #4

Comment: Can you put some sort of delimiter in there so I can see the line breaks. I ran the example you gave me and it output correctly.

Comment: @PS1 I see what you mean, I edited my post and ran it with your suggestion (swap lines 4 and 5) and it works correctly.